# Intergrate Laravel4 into an exisiting flat PHP site

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

Would like to integrate Laravel4's into an existing flat PHP-MySQL site,
while I am applying MCV logic page-by-page I need to keep this site work normally.

Before moving ahead: 
Q1.Does this intergration work at all ? 
Q2.Does anyone foresee any problem ?

Sofar I have only done this:

**app/routes.php**

```
Route::get('/', function(){

          //just keep empty, index.php shows up as intended.
});
```

**public/index.php**

```
test   

<?php
//Codes transplanted from Laravel4 
//.......start......
/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

It won't quite work this way.  In the middle of MVC we have our "Views" which are what laravel will return to the user for display.

What you **can** do, though, is put your index.php folder in the `app/views` directory.  If, for example, you put the content of your index.php file in:

`app/views/index.blade.php`

You can then call it via:

```
Route::get('/', function(){

          return View::make('index');
});
```

This will have the added benefit of getting you through your first step of moving from a "flat" PHP site and in to the framework.

**Note:**  If you DO try using the implementation you provide in your example, you're going to get a bunch of "Not Found" exceptions.